Removing the Policy Enforcement Google Workspace
I am trying to create a Key for the service account, but the inherited policy wont let me create this, therefore i tried to disable the parent policy inheritance but this throws an error. I am the organization admin. Attached is the error.enter image description here
can anyone please help me to get this resolved?
